# Flask user connecting different databases at login

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-login

I'm trying to make a system using Flask/Sqlalchemy to make user selecting a database at login. I already write the application, and I need to implement that new feature. So my idea is to bind the user's session to the Sqlalchemy engine. How ever I'm not sure how to do that without having to rewrite too much code.

I want  to initiate the engine like that at the beginning of the module.

```
# we create the engine
engine = create_engine(MSSQL_CONNECTION_STRING, echo=SQL_DEBUG, 
isolation_level='READ COMMITTED').connect()
# create the session
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
# Session object
session = db_session
```

I also have a User Class which contains the users definition, inheriting from UserMixIn. Should I add there a property "engine", which would hold the user's database selected on the login?

Then in the routes, i would need to setup the engine, from the User, but adding to every function would give me a lot of rewriting. As well, I need to pass the session inside the dbmodule functions which is using inside session as well.

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST','GET'])
def test():

engine = create_engine(user.engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = scoped_session(Session)
return dbmodule.function_that_do_some_stuff()
```

Comment: Does this work for you ? http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/binds/

Comment: no be cause i m not using flask-sqlalchemy but Flask AND sqlachemy